# How to Display an active item and the rest of the items next to it in Owl Carousel 2

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel-2

How to Display an active item and the rest of the items next to it in Owl Carousel 2?

this is my slider :

```
         <div class="slider-content d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap justify-content-between">

         <div class="slider-item">
             <figure>
                 <img class="img-fluid" src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="s">
             </figure>
         </div>

         <div class="slider-item">
             <figure>
                 <img class="img-fluid" src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="s">
             </figure>
         </div>


         <div class="slider-item">
             <figure>
                 <img class="img-fluid" src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="s">
             </figure>
         </div>

         <div class="slider-item">
             <figure>
                 <img class="img-fluid" src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="s">
             </figure>
         </div>
     </div>
```

and this is my javascript code :

```
    $(".slider-content").owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    rtl: true,
    autoplay:true
    }
);
```

Look at the picture below

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhLix.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Owl Carousel has an option called `center`, setting it to true will center your active item. https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html